# Modifying an JavaScript Array with Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having a strange problem and I can not figure out what is causing this.

I have, in JavaScript, an array of Objects.
Just like this one:

```
  var test = [{"title":"one"}, {"title":"two"}, {"title":"three"}, {"title":"four"}, {"title":"five"}, {"title":"six"}, {"title":"seven"}, {"title":"eight"}, {"title":"nine"}];
```

I am now trying to pick seven complete random entries (doesn't matter if I pick the same multiple times), add some values to the objects, and push it to a new array.
Like this:

```
    var schedule = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++) {

    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (test.length - 1));
    var temp = test[randomNumber];
    temp["id"] = i;

    schedule.push(temp);

}
```

What I expect to become:
An array, containing the following objects:

```
[{"title":"one", 0}, {"title":"three", 1}, {"title":"one", 2}, {"title":"two", 3}, {"title":"five", 4}, {"title":"one", 5}, {"title":"eight", 6}, {"title":"two", 7}]
```

BUT, and thats what I really don't understand, everytime an object reappers and gets pushed to the array, it overwrites its older entries.
I become an array like this:

```
[{"title":"one", 5}, {"title":"three", 1}, {"title":"one", 5}, {"title":"two", 7}, {"title":"five", 4}, {"title":"one", 5}, {"title":"eight", 6}, {"title":"two", 7}]
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Because you don't create new objects, just keep updating the same old ones? If you want to put a *copy* in schedule, do that *explicitly*.

Comment: Can u explain that a little more in depth? What exactly is wrong here and what would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: `schedule.push(temp);`  <= `temp` is a reference to an object in memory, that you found in the original array.  Both `temp` and `test[#]` point to the same object in memory.  So changing it will change it in both places.  So if in a later point in the loop you find the same element again, and change it, you will change the same element again, and all 3 references (on the second find) would reflect the change to the same element

Comment: Uhh, I see, thank you! What would be the correct way to create an independent copy?

Comment: You can clone the element.  One approach to a clone would be `var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourElement))`

Comment: Or if you know your objects only contain basic variable types you could also do `var temp = {...otherVariable}` to use deconstruction to do the clone

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: Also can use `var temp = Object.assign({}, test[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = [{
     "title": "one"
   }, {
     "title": "two"
   }, {
     "title": "three"
   }, {
     "title": "four"
   }, {
     "title": "five"
   }, {
     "title": "six"
   }, {
     "title": "seven"
   }, {
     "title": "eight"
   }, {
     "title": "nine"
   }];


   const result = test.map((x, i) => ({
     title: test[Math.floor(Math.random() * (test.length - 1))].title,
     id: i
   }));


   console.log(result)
```